# How to generate random data set with predicted probability?

Tags: r, simulation, prediction, categorical-data

I'm struggling to generate random data set with predicted probability of multinomial logistic regression.

Let's take an example. I'll use `nnet` package for multinomial logistic regression. I will also use `wine` data set in `rattle.data` package.

```
library("nnet")
library("rattle.data")
data(wine)
multinom.fit<-multinom(Type~Alcohol+Color,data=wine)
summary(multinom.fit)

Call:
multinom(formula = Type ~ Alcohol + Color - 1, data = wine)

Coefficients:
     Alcohol      Color
2  0.6258035 -1.9480658
3 -0.3457799  0.6944604

Std. Errors:
     Alcohol     Color
2 0.10203198 0.3204171
3 0.07042968 0.1479679

Residual Deviance: 222.5608 
AIC: 230.5608 

fit<-fitted(multinom.fit)
head(fit)

          1            2          3
1 0.6705935 0.0836177621 0.24578870
2 0.5050334 0.3847919037 0.11017466
3 0.6232029 0.0367975986 0.33999948
4 0.3895445 0.0007888818 0.60966664
5 0.4797392 0.4212542898 0.09900655
6 0.5510792 0.0077589278 0.44116190
```

So, the `fit` dataset is 178*3 dataframe. I want to generated 100 random dataset, using predicted probability. For example, the first sample in `fit` dataset has about 0.67 probability to be '1' and 0.08 to '2', 0.24 to '3'. Each sample was recruited(collected?) independently.

Is there a way to perform it?

Comment: Do you mean creating a new dataset with 100 observations / rows from `fit` using random sampling?

Comment: No, not 100 observations. The fit dataset has 178 rows(the sample units are 178). So I want to 100 different dataset with 178 observations

Comment: So, I assume you want to use resampling, right? Otherwise you'll end up with the same dataset 100 times...

Comment: For the first sample, Its code is `x <- sample( c(1:3), 100, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.67, 0.08, 0.24) )`. However, it has 178 sample, which means joint probability has to be considered.

Comment: Yes, the resampling with predicted probability is right.

Comment: Now I think I get it :) But it looks like you want 178 datasets (or vectors; one for each row of `fit`) of 100 observations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try:

```
rand.list <- lapply(1:nrow(fit), function(x) sample(1:3, 100, replace = TRUE, prob = fit[x, ]))
rand.df   <- data.frame(matrix(unlist(rand.list), ncol = nrow(fit)))
```

It will give you a data.frame with 100 observations and 178 columns with the different sampling probabilities of each row in `fit`.

Comment: Thanks, it work. But, it created 1 list with 178 components, which each component has 100 vector. For example, the first and second component of list is like this. '[[1]] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 3 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 [[2]] 2 1 3 1 1 2 3 2 1 2 1 3 1 2 2 1 3 1 2 1 3 2 1 1 1 3 1 1 2 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 3 1 1 3 2 2 1 3 1 2 3 1 2 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 3 3 1 1 3 1 3 1 3 1 2 1 3 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 1 1 1 3 3 1 3 3 1 3 1 3 1 3 3 2'

Comment: Is there a way to make 100 data.frame, which has 178 observation?

Comment: Yes, you can do it like this: `lapply(1:100, function(x) sample(1:3, 178, replace = TRUE, prob = fit[x, ]))` and then you transform it to a list of data.frame with `lapply`. But in this case you will only use the first 100 rows of `fit` and the other 78 will remain unused. Maybe you should an example of your expected result on the main post.

Comment: Hello, with your advice, I put the example of my expected results. I'm sorry for misconveying my words.

Comment: I edited my answer to give the result as a data.frame

Comment: Glad it worked. Check my last edit, I had mistaken ncol with nrow in the matrix function.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry for misconveying my words.

For example, When I execute your code, the results turn out like this.

```
head(lapply(1:nrow(fit), function(x) sample(1:3, 100, replace = TRUE, prob = fit[x, ])))
[[1]]
  [1] 1 1 3 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 3 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 3 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
 [61] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 3 3 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 3 1 1 1 1 1 1 1

[[2]]
  [1] 2 3 2 2 1 3 2 1 3 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 3 1 3 1 1 2 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 3 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 3 2 1 2 1 1 2 2 3 2 3 1 1 2 1 1 3 1 3 1
 [61] 2 1 2 1 3 1 1 1 2 3 3 1 1 3 1 3 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 3 3 2 1 1 2 1 2 1 3 3 1 1 1 2

[[3]]
  [1] 1 3 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 3 3 3 3 3 1 1 3 3 3 3 1 3 1 3 2 3 1 1 3 3 3 2 1 3 2 3 1 3 3 3 3 3 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 3 3 3 1 1 2 1 3 1 1 3
 [61] 3 3 3 3 1 1 1 3 3 3 3 1 1 1 1 1 3 1 3 1 1 3 1 1 1 1 3 3 3 1 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3

[[4]]
  [1] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 3 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 3 1 1 1 3 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
 [61] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 3 1 3 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 3 1 1 1 1 1 1 3 1 1 1 1 3 1 1 1 1 1 1 1

[[5]]
  [1] 1 3 2 1 1 1 1 1 3 2 1 2 1 2 1 1 1 3 3 3 1 2 2 3 1 1 2 1 2 1 3 3 1 1 3 3 2 3 2 1 1 2 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 3 3 1 2 2 3 1 1 1
 [61] 1 1 1 2 1 2 1 1 3 3 1 1 2 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 3 1 1 1 1 3

[[6]]
  [1] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 3 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 3 1 1 3 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 3 1 1 3 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
 [61] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 3 1 3 1 1 3 1 1 3 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

However, is there another way to express this in data.frame? when i execute data.frame function, it turn out like this.

```
head(data.frame(lapply(1:nrow(fit), function(x) sample(1:3, 100, replace = TRUE, prob = fit[x, ]))))
```

*Though executing head function, the data were to long. I copied the last two rows.

```
  c.3L..1L..3L..3L..3L..3L..3L..3L..3L..3L..3L..3L..3L..3L..3L..
1                                                              3
2                                                              1
3                                                              3
4                                                              3
5                                                              3
  c.3L..1L..1L..1L..3L..3L..3L..1L..1L..1L..3L..1L..1L..3L..1L..
1                                                              3
2                                                              1
3                                                              1
4                                                              1
5                                                              3
 [ reached 'max' / getOption("max.print") -- omitted 1 rows ]
```

I want to express the data like this.

```
   1 2 3 4 5 .... (ommited)
1 1 1 3 1 1
2 1 1 3 1 1
3 1 3 3 1 1
4 1 3 1 1 3
5 1 1 3 1 1
... (omited)
```

So, the data.frame is 178*100. 178 is the number of sample, and 100 is random generate trial number.