# Using lapply to each matrix of list

Tags: r, list, matrix, lapply, sample

I'm trying to use `lapply` to each matrix of the list.

I want to apply `sample` function, using `lapply`.

Let's take an example. I generated the probability, which will be used for `sample` function. (Sorry for not optimizing.)

```
set.seed(1001)
given<-replicate(3,list(matrix(unlist(replicate(5,sample(c(0.2,0.3,0.4,0.1),4,replace=FALSE),simplify=FALSE)),ncol=4)))
given   


   [[1]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]  0.1  0.4  0.2  0.4
[2,]  0.3  0.2  0.1  0.2
[3,]  0.2  0.1  0.1  0.3
[4,]  0.4  0.3  0.3  0.1
[5,]  0.3  0.4  0.2  0.4

[[2]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]  0.4  0.4  0.3  0.4
[2,]  0.3  0.1  0.4  0.2
[3,]  0.1  0.2  0.1  0.4
[4,]  0.2  0.1  0.3  0.3
[5,]  0.3  0.2  0.2  0.1

[[3]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]  0.3  0.2  0.2  0.1
[2,]  0.2  0.3  0.3  0.3
[3,]  0.1  0.4  0.2  0.2
[4,]  0.4  0.4  0.3  0.4
[5,]  0.1  0.1  0.4  0.1
```

So this list has three components, each component is a 5*4 matrix. Each row of the matrix(so, it has 15 rows) is given probability. I want to generate 10 samples with a given probability. For simplicity, I'll resample '1' to '4' with a given probability.

With the help of this document([How to generate random data set with predicted probability?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56866810/how-to-generate-random-data-set-with-predicted-probability)), I learned to apply `sample` function to a component of one matrix. If `given` were one matrix, I would execute this function.

`lapply(1:nrow(given), function(x) sample(1:4, 10, replace = TRUE, prob = given[x, ]))`

But, as you can see, `given` is a list with 3 matrices. I tried several attempts, like `prob=given$x`, `prob=given[[x,]]`, etc.... but it all failed. Is there a way to apply it?

*additional question

To Ronak Shah

It turned out perfectly right. Thanks!

However, sorry for not asking all quesion. In fact, there was some missing data in probability set.

I'll make one row in `given` set missing value.

```
given[[2]][1,]<-NA
given

[[1]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]  0.1  0.4  0.2  0.4
[2,]  0.3  0.2  0.1  0.2
[3,]  0.2  0.1  0.1  0.3
[4,]  0.4  0.3  0.3  0.1
[5,]  0.3  0.4  0.2  0.4

[[2]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]   NA   NA   NA   NA
[2,]  0.3  0.1  0.4  0.2
[3,]  0.1  0.2  0.1  0.4
[4,]  0.2  0.1  0.3  0.3
[5,]  0.3  0.2  0.2  0.1

[[3]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]  0.3  0.2  0.2  0.1
[2,]  0.2  0.3  0.3  0.3
[3,]  0.1  0.4  0.2  0.2
[4,]  0.4  0.4  0.3  0.4
[5,]  0.1  0.1  0.4  0.1
```

After reading your answer, I manipulate some code in your answers. But the results was quite different.

```
 lapply(given, function(x) t(sapply(seq_len(nrow(x)), function(y)
 ifelse(is.na(x[y,]),NA,sample(1:4, 10, replace = TRUE, prob = x[y, ])))))

[[1]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    4    4    4    2
[2,]    2    3    2    2
[3,]    4    4    1    1
[4,]    1    3    1    1
[5,]    3    3    1    1

[[2]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]   NA   NA   NA   NA
[2,]    3    4    3    2
[3,]    4    2    2    2
[4,]    4    2    1    1
[5,]    1    2    4    1

[[3]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    1    2    2
[2,]    3    4    3    4
[3,]    2    3    2    4
[4,]    2    4    4    2
[5,]    2    3    3    3
```

As you can see, the NA turned out right, but it only generated 4 samples, not 10 samples.
Would you please show me how to solve this problem?

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry. I corrected it.

Comment: @RonakShah Yes. I would be appropriate.

Comment: @patL Each matrix has four columns and it has 4 lengths. Isn't it appropriate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without over-complicating it too much and continuing from your attempt, we can use `sapply` inside `lapply`. `lapply` would loop over each list whereas `sapply` would loop over every row in the list.

```
lapply(given, function(x) t(sapply(seq_len(nrow(x)), function(y) 
             sample(1:4, 10, replace = TRUE, prob = x[y, ]))))

#[[1]]
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
#[1,]    2    3    4    4    3    4    4    4    2     1
#[2,]    1    1    1    2    4    1    2    2    2     3
#[3,]    1    4    4    1    4    1    1    2    2     4
#[4,]    1    1    3    2    3    2    3    1    1     3
#[5,]    4    2    3    1    2    2    1    4    1     4

#[[2]]
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
#[1,]    1    3    2    3    2    1    1    1    2     1
#[2,]    3    1    1    1    3    3    2    3    1     4
#[3,]    4    3    4    2    4    4    4    4    4     4
#[4,]    3    3    4    4    3    4    4    2    3     4
#[5,]    1    1    2    2    4    1    1    2    1     4

#[[3]]
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
#[1,]    3    1    1    2    1    3    3    1    2     1
#[2,]    4    4    3    1    3    3    3    3    2     4
#[3,]    1    1    2    2    2    3    4    4    2     4
#[4,]    2    1    4    4    1    3    3    4    4     1
#[5,]    3    3    3    3    3    3    1    2    3     3
```

---

To handle `NA` values we can do

```
lapply(given, function(x) t(sapply(seq_len(nrow(x)), function(y) 
      if (anyNA(x[y,])) rep(NA, 10) else 
         sample(1:4, 10, replace = TRUE, prob = x[y, ]))))
```

Comment: It turned out right. However, there is a new problem. I added the new problem in original text. Would you please answer it?

Comment: @ESKim so when you have probability as `NA` what output would you like? 10 values with `NA`?  Also what if there is only 1 or 2 `NA` in the row. What would be the output in that case?

Comment: I would print 10 values with `NA`.

Comment: It was really helpful. Thanks!

Comment: I'm sorry for asking one more question after a while. What does `seq_len` mean in your code? As I know, in `apply` function, there must be a data in first section, like `apply(data, function(x) {~})`.

Comment: @ESKim `seq_len(nrow(x))` is another way to write `1:nrow(x)` as in your attempt. Check `seq_len(nrow(mtcars))` and `1:nrow(mtcars)`. But it is safer because if you have an empty dataframe, `seq_len(0)` gives different result than `1:0`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, then what does `1:nrow(mtcars)` mean in that code? As I know, there should be a data in that position, which will be used for analyzing.

Comment: @ESKim you can use `1:nrow(x)` instead of `seq_len(nrow(x))`. It wouldn't matter here.